# How to mock constructor inside node_module with jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, cote

Jest has an option to mock `node_module`:

`jest.mock('module_name')`

Module I am trying to mock is `cote` module.
[Here](https://github.com/dashersw/cote/blob/master/src/index.js) is an index.js file from the module.

inside it has contructor for `Requester` exported

```
const Requester = require('./components/requester');

...

cote.Requester = Requester;

...

module.exports = cote();
```

I access this file in my code like this:

```
const cote = require('cote');
const requester = new cote.Requester({name: 'findOnePlayer requester'});

...

const player = await requester.send({type:'findOnePlayer',username:username, password: password})
```

How to set up with `jest` so that constructor of `Requester` from mocked `cote` module returns mocked object that resolves a promise when you call send?

EDIT:
I need this case in many tests, and each `send(...` should return different promise per test scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "manual mock" of the module that you first create in `__mocks__`, and then import into your tests using `jest.mock('moduleName')`, will allow you to mock the `requester` object in your code.

To generate different output each time `requester.send()` is called, one can make use of mock function implementations; i.e. `jest.fn()` and chained `jest.mockImplementationOnce()` invocations. For example:

```
const send = jest
  .fn(() => new Promise(resolve => resolve('foo')))
  .mockImplementationOnce(() => new Promise(resolve => resolve('bar')))
  .mockImplementationOnce(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject()));
```

When you run successive tests where you execute this mocked `send()` function, the promises returned by `send()` will resolve with the values we specified above. For more details, check out the documentation here:

Manual mocks:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks

Mock Implementations:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-implementations

Comment: what would be approach then to create different response in different test with `request.send(`?